# XML encryption and decryption for multiple recipients with X509 certificates

Tags: c#, .net, xml, encryption, certificate

I have managed to encrypt and decrypt xml documents using examples on MSDN.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229744.aspx and
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229943.aspx

This is all done according to the W3C XML encryption standard(XML Enc).

It all works good. My problem is that one xml document is intended for 2 or 3 recipients. I want to encrypt same xml with multiple keys (X509 certificate public key) so that document could be decrypted by multiple recipients.

This is all possible according to the W3C XML encryption standard by using multiple EncryptionKey elements that contain encrypted symmetric session key.

I couldn't find any example on how to achieve this in .Net using standard cryptography classes.

This must be implemented in .NET C#.

Is there a way to do this or code example somewhere?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, and thanks for the interesting question. Let's hope somebody with enough .NET knowledge can answer it. Note that you should always include a language tag. You don't need to put the language in the title though.

Comment: I'm not even a C# developer, but I think Stackoverflow should know this...

Comment: I dont think its a good idea: http://arstechnica.com/business/2011/10/researchers-break-w3c-encryption-standard-for-xml/, here is the [paper](http://www.nds.ruhr-uni-bochum.de/media/nds/veroeffentlichungen/2011/10/22/HowToBreakXMLenc.pdf).

Comment: @JeremyThompson I know of that attack. Even better, I implemented a similar Padding Oracle attack on XML encryption before I read the paper. Furthermore I wrote an implementation for WDSL security that always checks the XML signature before decryption before they published the paper. As in all attacks, it depends on the threat model if the attack applies. It certainly has little to do with having multiple recipients or not. Always authenticating *all* your data in a communication channel before decryption should be enough.

Comment: @owlstead Show-off ;-)

Comment: I know about XML encryption weakness but we will be using private secured line for data exchange and it will not be used in web services. We are using standalone xml documents that contain base64 encoded data. We will use Xml digital signature above encrypted data. The only problem is how to avoid sending multiple documents encrypted with different keys. The only elegant solution is encrypting for multiple recipients within the same document. Max number of recipients will be 3 permanently.

Comment: By modifying the linked MSDN examples I could get it to encrypt the message for multiple X509 recipients relatively painlessly, but I ran into an issue when decrypting.  I might be doing it wrong, but the EncryptedXml.DecryptDocument() method seems to always try to use the first EncryptedKey it finds rather than looking for a known recipient.  I could work around the problem by manually removing the EncryptedKey elements for unknown recipients before decrypting, but that seemed like such a hack that I felt I was doing it wrong or it's just not officially supported.

Comment: @RogerN, I added the code needed to decrypt to my example.  You would use the KeyName to select the appropriate key.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The EncryptedElement class can take as many EncryptedKeys as you want.  As long as the other party can correctly identify their EncryptedKey (using the Recipient or the KeyInfoName elements), you should not have any problems:

```
// example xml
XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
xdoc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
xdoc.LoadXml(@"<root><encryptme>hello world</encryptme></root>");

var elementToEncrypt = (XmlElement)xdoc.GetElementsByTagName("encryptme")[0];

// keys
// rsa keys would normally be pulled from a store
RSA rsaKey1 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
RSA rsaKey2 = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
var publicKeys = new[] { rsaKey1, rsaKey2 };

string sessKeyName = "helloworldkey";
var sessKey = new RijndaelManaged() { KeySize = 256 };

// encrypt
var encXml = new EncryptedXml();
var encryptedElement = new EncryptedData()
{
    Type = EncryptedXml.XmlEncElementUrl,
    EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncAES256Url),
    KeyInfo = new KeyInfo()
};
encryptedElement.CipherData.CipherValue = encXml.EncryptData(elementToEncrypt, sessKey, false);
encryptedElement.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoName(sessKeyName));

// encrypt the session key and add keyinfo's
int keyID = 0;
foreach (var pk in publicKeys)
{
    var encKey = new EncryptedKey()
    {
        CipherData = new CipherData(EncryptedXml.EncryptKey(sessKey.Key, pk, false)),
        EncryptionMethod = new EncryptionMethod(EncryptedXml.XmlEncRSA15Url),
        Recipient = string.Format("recipient{0}@foobar.com", ++keyID),
        CarriedKeyName = sessKeyName,
    };
    encKey.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoName(encKey.Recipient));
    encryptedElement.KeyInfo.AddClause(new KeyInfoEncryptedKey(encKey));
}

// update the xml
EncryptedXml.ReplaceElement(elementToEncrypt, encryptedElement, false);

// show the result
Console.Write(xdoc.InnerXml);
Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine(new string('-', 80));
```

Produces

```
<root>
    <EncryptedData Type="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#Element" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
        <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#aes256-cbc" />
        <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
            <KeyName>helloworldkey</KeyName>
            <EncryptedKey Recipient="recipient1@foobar.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <KeyName>recipient1@foobar.com</KeyName>
                </KeyInfo>
                <CipherData>
                    <CipherValue>bmVT4SuAgWto6NJoTnUhrwaQ5/bWx39WKfs8y/QEQbaEBqdvl2Wa3woQGZxfigZ2wsWZQJFW0YGMII0W6AATnsqGOOVEbdGxmnvXRISiRdhcyNHkHot0kDK987y446ws5CZQQuz8inGq/SNrhiK6RyVnBE4ykWjrJyIS5wScwqA=</CipherValue>
                </CipherData>
                <CarriedKeyName>helloworldkey</CarriedKeyName>
            </EncryptedKey>
            <EncryptedKey Recipient="recipient2@foobar.com" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#">
                <EncryptionMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#rsa-1_5" />
                <KeyInfo xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#">
                    <KeyName>recipient2@foobar.com</KeyName>
                </KeyInfo>
                <CipherData>
                    <CipherValue>oR8NPTm1NasWeDXBjayLk+p9/5RTWOZwNJHUMTQpZB9v1Aasi75oSjGqSqN0HMTiviw6NWz8AvHB9+i08L4Hw8JRDLxZgjaKqTGu31wXmM3Vc0CoYQ15AWMZN4q4tSxDhwuT8fp9SN+WFBm+M3w3bcPoooAazzDHK3ErzfXzYiU=</CipherValue>
                </CipherData>
                <CarriedKeyName>helloworldkey</CarriedKeyName>
            </EncryptedKey>
        </KeyInfo>
        <CipherData>
            <CipherValue>ohjWIEFf2WO6v/CC+ugd7uxEKGJlxgdT9N+t3MhoTIyXHqT5VlknWs0XlAhcgajkxKFjwVO3p413eRSMTLXKCg==</CipherValue>
        </CipherData>
    </EncryptedData>
</root>
```

To decrypt the document, you must provide a mapping between the key name and the private key of the certificate:

```
// Decrypt
string myKeyName = "recipient1@foobar.com";

// specify we want to use the key for recipient1
var encryptedDoc = new EncryptedXml(xdoc);
encryptedDoc.AddKeyNameMapping(myKeyName, rsaKey1);
encryptedDoc.Recipient = myKeyName;

// Decrypt the element.
encryptedDoc.DecryptDocument();

// show the result
Console.Write(xdoc.InnerXml);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Result:

```
<root><encryptme>hello world</encryptme></root>
```

Comment: I'll wait for a verdict of the original asker, but this is looking good. I'm a bit amazed about the namespaces (digsig?), but two receipients in the `SignedInfo`... Should be it.

Comment: This is very similar to the solution I tried, but I get an exception if I try to decrypt using the 2nd key name instead of the 1st.  I tried your code and it seems to have the same issue.

Comment: @RogerN, seems I was missing a KeyInfo element.  You also have to specify the Recipient field on the EncryptedXml object when decrypting.  Should be fixed now.

Comment: @Mitch, first of all, thank you for your solution. It works! I had code similar to yours and now I see I was pretty close to solution. And again, thank you. I lost days trying to do this.

Comment: @Bokina don't forget to vote up and accept the answer if it suits your needs