# how to identify the correct server cert from same client using multiple certs

Tags: c#, .net, ssl-certificate

I've situation where I need to renew my server cert and pass on the same to my client to encrypt the data, but my client can't afford down time and want to update the cert on their end in a rolling fashion, which means that they want to send the requests using both the certs, but few of my client's servers use old cert and few use new cert. How can I handle this at my end to serve the requests seamlessly, I should be able to identify which cert they passed and decrypt the data using the corresponding cert. Client is not ready to make any change to tell me which cert they are using. I'm using .net 4.6 frame work. Please help me if anyone faced this issue before and how you solved this.

Comment: You need to modify your software so that it will accept a message encrypted with either cert. You then need to offer your clients a time window during which both will be accepted. At the end of the window you would then disable the old cert.

Comment: What do you mean `encrypt the data`? You used the `ssl-certificate` tag. HTTPS is transparent to the code. As long as you install a new certificate on the server, clients will use it.

Comment: @JohnWu - so I need to first try to decrypt the data with the new cert and if it fails then use the old cert to decrypt it ? Or any other way around ?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - some of the confidential data in the request will be encrypted using that cert's public key and at the server I decrypt those fields using the private key of that cert.

Comment: Worst case, you can try decrypting using all certificates one at a time until one succeeds. Otherwise the encrypted "message" needs to specify which certificate was used. That's what happens with eg the `EnvelopedCms` class which is used to encrypt emails for multiple recipients using their certificates. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66141024/134204) shows how it's used. You'll have to change the client code though